# Как составить регулярное выражение на проверку URL c++?

Tags: c++

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой, у меня есть строка, обозначим ее string url; как можно првоерить на то, чтобы она была валидным url с указанным протоколом соединения, и если протокола нет, то сконконтинировать его со строкой считая что протокол http? И как потом из этой строки с валидным URL (если он вообще валидный), выделить домен? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

char url[] = "stackoverflow.com";
char protocol[] = "http://";
char result[50] = "";
char domain[20] = "";
if ((strncmp(url, protocol, strlen(protocol)) != 0)) { //если url не начинается на http://
    strcpy(result, protocol); //в результирующую строку добавляем протокол
    strcat(result, url); //и исходный url
}
else {
    strcpy(result, url); //в противном случае просто копируем url
}

int i = strlen(protocol), j = 0;
while (result[i] != '.') { //проходим по url, пока не дойдём до разделителя-точки
    domain[j++] = result[i++]; //и копируем символы до точки в качестве домена
}

std::cout << result << std::endl; //http://stackoverflow.com
std::cout << domain << std::endl; //stackoverflow

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Хочу обратить Ваше внимание на то, что это не универсальное решение: если исходный `url` имеет `субдомен(ы)` (e.g. `ru.stackoverflow.com`), то программа будет работать некорректно. Однако набросок у Вас уже есть, успехов!